# Android performance optimization Scheduling Delay

Tags: android, performance, android-viewpager, android-textinputlayout

I have a `ViewPager` in an Activity with each fragment containing 4,5 `TextInputLayouts`. When a open activity from `NavigationMenu` it causes a **small delay** before opening the activity. I took a `systrace` to figure out what's going on. Most of the time I get some issues, reporting `Scheduling Delays`. While I have studied about Scheduling Delays but **I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong on my side as I am just inflating the layouts and no background or other heavy work is being done on UI thread**. Following is scheduling delay reported in `systrace`

```
Running 
85.094 ms
Not scheduled, but runnable 
1.949 ms
Blocking I/O delay  
0.259 ms
Sleeping    
13.885 ms
Frame   
Description 
Work to produce this frame was descheduled for several milliseconds, contributing to jank. Ensure that code on the UI thread doesn't block on work being done on other threads, and that background threads (doing e.g. network or bitmap loading) are running at android.os.Process#THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND or lower so they are less likely to interrupt the UI thread. These background threads should show up with a priority number of 130 or higher in the scheduling section under the Kernel process.
```

[image: cpu profiler]

Also `Inefficient View alpha usage` alerts are being reported in `systrace` because of `HeiglightView` which I can't find in my layout's view heirarcy nor I am using it anywhere.

```
view name   
"HighlightView"
width   
990
height  
55
HighlightView alpha caused saveLayer 990x55 took 0.01ms
Description 
Setting an alpha between 0 and 1 has significant performance costs, if one of the fast alpha paths is not used.
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/attach_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_cloud_upload"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/attach_image_to_upload" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/creator_name"
                    app:validation_key="@string/validator_non_empty"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/attach_image"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="400"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:hint="@string/creator_name"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/survey_name"
                    app:validation_key="@string/validator_non_empty"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/creator_name"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="400"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:hint="@string/survey_name"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/order_number"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                    app:validation_key="@string/validator_non_empty"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/survey_name"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:maxLength="400"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:hint="@string/order_number"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/prize"
                    app:validation_key="@string/validator_non_empty"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_number"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="400"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:hint="@string/prize"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    app:validation_key="@string/validator_non_empty"
                    app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/prize"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:maxLength="400"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                        android:hint="@string/description"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</layout>
```

View Hierarchy

[image: view hierarchy]